# At what rate do players and commanders receive resources per resource node?

Tags: natural-selection-2

How many resources does a player get per second (on average) per resource node captured?

How about for the commander?

Does it differ between aliens or marines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the NS2 wiki, resource towers provide 0.125 personal resource and 1 team resource every 6 seconds.

It's the same rate for both marines and aliens.

Team resources cap at 200, personal resources cap at 100.

If a player has 100 personal resources and would gain more, the excess is distributed evenly among his teammates.

Comment: As an aside, this means that it takes 60 seconds for a resource tower to pay for itself once it is built. (Alien harvesters take 45 seconds to build, if not being healed)