# How are resources gained, distributed, and spent?

Tags: natural-selection-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what rate do players and commanders receive resources per resource node?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92180/at-what-rate-do-players-and-commanders-receive-resources-per-resource-node)

I'm unclear on how resources gained by aliens and marines are gained and distributed to the teams and personal supplies.

**First, how is the amount and frequency res gained calculated?** I know it's a function of res nodes over time, but what's the actual equation? Is res gained even if the team doesn't have any resource nodes captured? Does going from one res node to two double the amount of res gained, or is it a different scale?

**Second, how are the resources gathered distributed to the team (i.e., comm) and individual members of the team?** Do players with with a higher "score" gain a higher percentage of the distribution? Is it based on how long a player has been alive or how much he's contributed to the team? Physical proximity to certain structures? Can a commander manually give extra resources to a player?

**Third, is there anything the effects the costs of spending resources?** Does evolving into an Onos *always* cost 75 resources? As an alien, is there a cost difference between going from a skulk to fade versus lurk to fade? As a commander, are some upgrades cheaper sooner or later depending on your current tech-tree? Do any structures offer a "discount" or "rebate"? Does doing well in a match effect any of these costs?

This may be a question overload, but there you go! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

1) Resource towers provide 0.125 personal resource and 1 team resource every 6 seconds.

It's the same rate for both marines and aliens.

You accumulate fractional amounts, but can only spend whole resource points.

Personal resources cap at 100, team resources cap at 200.

2) Players on the same team gain personal resources at the same rate.

One exception, though, is if a player has the maximum allowed 100 personal resources and would gain more, the excess is distributed evenly among his teammates.

A commander cannot directly transfer team resources to a player as personal resources.  But, marine commanders can purchase weapons, jetpacks, exo suits, etc. with team resources for their troops to use.  Likewise, alien commanders can expend team resources to buy eggs of gorge, lerk, fade, and onos for their team to evolve into.

3)  Resource costs are static, there are no discounts.  E.g. going into gorge and then lerk will cost 40 resources, as opposed to only 30 if you go directly to lerk.

The only way to get a "rebate" is as marine commander.  By recycling structures you can regain up to 50% of the team resource cost of a structure.